# Template integer parameter constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I don't understand the following constructor (part of Qt library in src\corelib\tools\qstringbuilder.h), what does it mean and how does it work?

```
class QLatin1Literal
{
public:
    int size() const { return m_size; }
    const char *data() const { return m_data; }

    template <int N>
    QLatin1Literal(const char (&str)[N])
        : m_size(N - 1), m_data(str) {}

private:
    const int m_size;
    const char * const m_data;
};
```

Comment: N here is a Nontype template Parameter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The constructor is taking string literal as an argument. What you see is just a syntax to declare a template for this.

With such constructor m_size can be found in O(1) opposed to O(strlen(str)) required otherwise with a non-template constructor taking `char const*` as an argument.

A thing to remember of is for each string length there will be an instance of template generated by compiler so you may end up having quite a few instantiations of this template in your library/binary/object files.

Comment: +1, but I'd say these "instantiations" actually get inlined and never really make it into the binary as standalone.

Comment: @Andrew - agree, with inlining impact will only be a slight increase in compilation time, not a binary size.

Comment: Another important thing to remember here is due to special casing, when a `const char*` overload is present, that one would be chosen over the template one, even though it seems to be a better match (no decay needed).

Answer (score 8):

The constructor argument is a reference to an array of `N` characters. It initialises `m_data` to point to the first character, and `m_size` to one less than the size of the array.

A string literal, like `"hello"`, is an array of characters containing those in the string, followed by a zero-valued terminator. So, if the constructor is called with one of those:

```
 QLatin1Literal lit("hello");
 assert(lit.size() == strlen("hello"));  // SUCCESS: m_size is inferred as 5
```

it will infer a value of 6 for `N` (since the array contains the five characters of "hello", plus the terminator), and initialise `m_size` to 5 (the actual string length).

Beware that this could go wrong if the array isn't actually a string literal; for example:

```
char buffer[1000] = "hello";  // array size is larger than string+terminator
QLatin1Literal lit(buffer);
assert(lit.size() == strlen("hello"));  // FAIL: m_size is inferred as 999
```

Answer (score 3):

It means that `str` is a reference to an array of `N` constant characters. It simply means that the constructor takes as argument an array of characters, like for example a string literal.